# JQuery - Event do not fire for element under some other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am facing a situation where I want to handle `click` event of `li` that is present under another element with class `optWrapper`. Most of these mark-up is generated due to third party `javascript` libraries. So, markup is something like

```
   <div class="optWrapper multiple open">
       <ul class="options">
           <li data-val="7"><span><i></i></span><label>Critical Illness</label></li>
          <li data-val="25"><span><i></i></span><label>Critical Illness Insurance</label></li>
         <li data-val="3"><span><i></i></span><label>Critical Illness Silver</label></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

and my `jQuery` code is

```
$(".optWrapper li").click(function () {
     alert();
 });
```

I can't find why this event is not getting called. Please help.

**Edit 1**

I am guessing this behavior is due to these element are loaded after jquery has downloaded in browser, is it that? if yes, than how could I tackle with it?

**Edit 2**
These element are dynamically generated after dropdownlist's select event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of onsubject is correct. Saying to use .on instead of .click.

After jQuery 1.7 the preferred method is .on()

Addition on the answer of @onsubject , because his answer won't work, on dynamically created

```
".optWrapper li"
```

Instead of the actual element, use the body or its parent element.

```
$('body').on('click', '.optWrapper li', function() {
//do something
}
```

Comment: this is one what I wanted :) but it's executing 3 times :(

Comment: must be your code. here is an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvPWzg  it only fire once

Comment: It would be nice if you could make a jsfiddle.net version of your code.

Comment: please give whole html code for better understanding @Imadoddin Ibn Alauddin

Comment: Here you go,  a full example of what you want https://jsfiddle.net/139uxh9c/  with dynamic creation of element

Answer (score 1):

> These element are dynamically generated after dropdownlist's select event.

Oops, your event listener attached before creation.
As javascript event bubbles up target to document, you can handle that event by listening parent of them. [See Direct and delegated events section](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Attach event listener to the parent which don't generate dynamically.

```
$('#someparent').on("click","li.your_target",function(){
    alert();
});
```

Comment: it helped me but andrews answer was ultimate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your jquery code in  `$(document).ready(function (){});`
It will work fine.

Comment: It doesn't, because these elements are not available on ready.

Comment: fiddle will work, no doubt, because all the `li` are available as dom is ready. My case is different, see edit1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on instead of .click

```
$(".optWrapper li").on("click", function () {
     alert();
});
```

See a working version here:
http://codepen.io/ramiror/pen/zGeXPO

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".optWrapper ul li").live('click', function(e){
        alert("eureka");
    });
});
```